# How do I refresh db and app at same time?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a stored proc that grabs that data from a table, let's call it table1 from one db1 and populates a table, called table2 in db2.

We scheduled this stored proc to perform this function like every 5 minutes. This works fine.

Given that users mostly leave their apps while performing other administrative functions, we have created a refresh button that refreshes the GridView upon clicking the button.

```
Protected Sub Refresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Refresh.Click
    ' Clean up text to return the GridView to it's default state
      strSearch.Text = ""
      SearchString = ""
      gridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

We would like to both click this refresh button to both to have the stored procedure update table2 and at same time, refresh the GridView.

I know that `gridview1.Databind()` refreshes the GridView with latest data from table2 but how do I ensure that table2 is first updated with data from table1 using the stored proc before refreshing the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenny I have prepared complete code in vb for you, take a look:

```
Private Sub CallRefresh()
     Dim connectionString As String = "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;data source=myServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
     Dim storedProcName As String = "ActivateServerTask"
     Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
     conn.Open()
     Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(storedProcName, conn)
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@taskId", 1))
     command.ExecuteNonQuery()
     command.Dispose()
     conn.Close()
     conn.Dispose()
 End Sub


 Protected Sub Refresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles     Refresh.Click       
      CallRefresh()
      gridView1.DataBind()       
 End Sub
```

CallRefresh opens connection, executes "ActivateServerTask" stored procedure with "taskId" parameter and finally closes connection...
Take notice I am using connection to sql with integrated security.
You can find other connection strings here:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Happy coding Kenny!

Comment: thank you very much for your help.

We are using 4 parameters to grab data from one db and insert that data into another db.

That said, if I add 3 more command.Parameters.Add(...) like the one below:     command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@taskId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)), that's all we need to do and it works?

Comment: Yes. Just be sure to change connection string, proc name and pass parameters with correct type. Note that you can add new parameter using folowing code:
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter([parameter_name], [actual_parameter_value]))

Comment: hi @Gregor, hopefully, you could help out on this but I keep getting the error that "Could not find stored procedure 'EditEmp'"

Any idea why I keep getting this error? The SP is there and I can see it.

Thanks

Comment: This error does basicly tell you the real problem, stored proc with this name does not exists.
Double check if you are realy connecting to the same database as you are viewing at. What kind of database are you accessing (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Access,...)?
I have noticed you have " inside stored procedure name, just check you code where you enter procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

Just call your stored procedure from application before you call gridView1.DataBind()

This is how you call a stored procedure from your code:

```
public object ExecuteStoredProcedureAsValue(SqlConnection conn, 
                                            string storedProcName, 
                                            List<SqlParameter> parameters) 
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, conn)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (parameters != null)
            parameters.ForEach(p => command.Add(param));

        object result = null;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result = reader[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Take notice that "conn" is SqlConnection object. You should initialize and open sql connection before calling this code.

Comment: Please don't sign your questions or answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel. Do I need to call this function in Sub Refresh_Click event? How do I use it?

Also, what do you mean by don't sign your questions or answers?

Comment: FYI : You do not need to call the reader.Close method. It will be taken care by the **using** block

Comment: @Shyju, Dennis and Gregor, I still need to know how to use it. Do I use it to replace Refresh_Click event or call it there? 

If call it in Refresh_Click, how do I use it?

Thanks alot

Comment: @Gregor, any idea how I can use your code along with the Refresh_Click sub I posted?

Comment: @Kenny, we can't answer that unless you tell us the the name of the stored procedure and what parameters it takes.

Comment: Ok, thanks @SteveDog. The name of the stored proc is GetDataSP and it takes 4 parameters, all string